# Get children class using image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have using images src

```
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 disp" data-src="uploads/slider_img/negy.jpg">
   <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="uploads/slider_img/negy.jpg"></a>
   <div class="content"><img class="imageclass" src="img/hotspot.png" width="30px" height="30px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="top:243px; left:1024px; z-index: 1; position: absolute;">
      <div class="child" style="top:234px; left:1074px;">
         <h4>dfgh</h4>
         <p>fghdg</p>
         <div class="triangle-down"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

how to I call content child class depend image src

```
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 disp" data-src="uploads/slider_img/negx.jpg">
   <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="uploads/slider_img/negx.jpg"></a>
   <div lass="content"><img class="imageclass" src="img/hotspot.png" width="30px" height="30px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="top:490px; left:1188px; z-index: 1; position: absolute;">
      <div class="child" style="top:481px; left:1238px;">
         <h4>sa</h4>
         <p>sas</p>
         <div class="triangle-down"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, can you explain little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

In order to select the next `div.content` you can use Javascript or jQuery.

Here is an example, using your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('src') === 'uploads/slider_img/negx.jpg') {
      $(this).parent().next().css("background-color", "red");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 disp" data-src="uploads/slider_img/negx.jpg">
  <a href="">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="uploads/slider_img/negx.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="content">
  <img class="imageclass" src="img/hotspot.png" width="30px" height="30px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="top:490px; left:1188px; z-index: 1; position: absolute;">
    <div class="child" style="top:481px; left:1238px;">
      <h4>sa</h4>
      <p>sas</p>
      <div class="triangle-down"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

**Notes:**

- I'm selecting each image in the document, and iterating through them using `each()`
- If the image `src` attribute match the path that I'm looking for, then go up in the hierarchy with `parent()` and select the next sibling with `next()`
- Finally, apply the css styling with `css()`